# Firestore broken after AndroidX migrate

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, androidx

I have just migrate to AndroidX and update my Flutter dependencies.

I have error now when use Firestore.

For example:

```
//try {
 await ref.collection(‘collection’).document(document).updateData({
    'Field’: field,
  });
//} catch (e) {
//  debugPrint(e.toString());
//}
```

Freeze app and give stack error:

```
StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (message_codecs.dart:564) MethodChannel.invokeMethod (platform_channel.dart:292)
_RootZone.runUnary (zone.dart:1379)
_FutureListener.handleValue (future_impl.dart:126)
_Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (future_impl.dart:639)
_Future._propagateToListeners (future_impl.dart:668)
_Future._completeWithValue (future_impl.dart:483)
_Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (future_impl.dart:513)
_microtaskLoop (schedule_microtask.dart:41)
_startMicrotaskLoop (schedule_microtask.dart:50)
```

`message_codecs` break on exception (564) is:

```
throw PlatformException(code: errorCode, message: errorMessage, details: errorDetails);
```

When catch error error is:

```
PlatformException(Error 0, null, null)
```

I am use:

```
cloud_firestore: ^0.9.0+2
(firebase_auth: ^0.8.1+1)
(google_sign_in: ^4.0.1+1)
(firebase_messaging: ^3.0.1)
```

No same issue on Android.

Thanks for help!

Update: This not same issue as https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28103. Removing `await` not fix freeze/issue.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem.
This is a bug of v0.9.0+2.

It solved it by using the previous version of cloud_firestore.

```
  cloud_firestore:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/flutter/plugins.git
      path: packages/cloud_firestore
      ref: 51696552700af8692fd7d595237fc9c4e273de93
```

Flutter seems to recognize +1 and +2 as the same version.
Even if 0.9.0+1 was specified, it did not change.
So I did the following.

1. Deleting `.pub-cache/`,
2. Specify the above version
3. `flutter packages get`
4. `cloud_firestore: 0.9.0+1`
5. `flutter packages get`